# Read records from database using Active Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I have written the following code snippet to read data from the database :

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'active_resource'

    class Website < ActiveResource::Base
      self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
    end

    websites = Website.find(:all)
    puts websites.inspect
```

this gives me following output :

```
prompt:~/Desktop$ ruby active_resource_example.rb
=> nil
```

My websites table contains the following fields :

```
    == Schema Information

 Table name: websites

  id          :integer(4)      not null, primary key
  name        :string(255)
  url         :string(255)
  description :text
  active      :boolean(1)      default(TRUE)
  created_at  :datetime
  updated_at  :datetime
```

There are records present in my websites table, but why it is showing me nil result. This is the simplest code I could write and still not getting the required result.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You somehow need to tell it how to access the database...

Comment: I have written this code as given in the api, but it is not giving me the expected output.as shown here :http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base

Comment: Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: Is this a rails question, or just active record, without all of rails?

Comment: I think rails tag is needed - `ActiveResource` is some kind of gateway to rails.

Comment: This functionality will be use to automate the process of reading and updating the database by associating the ruby code with the cronjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should start web server through call `rails server` command. I think you already prepared this because in the opposite case you received some errors about connection. Later, you must be sure that your routes contains something like this:

```
resources :websites
```

and your website controller contains `format.json` section in `respond_to` block.
At last you can check logs - after preparing `Website.find(:all)` call (to the point - you can use `Website.all`) you should receive following record:

```
Started GET "/websites.json" for ....
```

Comment: thanks man..got it working. Actually I was not not providing the site properly. That's why it was not working. site should have been given as 'http://localhost:3000/admin/' ,as the resource was present in admin section.